# Sockets in android to check real time data change

Tags: java, android, sockets

I have to monitor server at real time. Means if there is any change happens in server value need to display it in android device . I have code to implement the same in web browser using html java script .

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function webservice_connect() {
 //  open a web socket
 hostname = window.location.hostname;
 ws = new WebSocket('ws://'+hostname+':8000/echo');
 ws.onopen = function()
 {
console.log("connected to server");
 }
 ws.onmessage = function (evt) 
 { 
    var received_msg = evt.data;
    //alert("Message is received...");
    console.log("Message is received..."+received_msg);
rdata = JSON.parse(received_msg);   
show_status(rdata);
 };
 ws.onclose = function()
 { 
    // websocket is closed.
console.log("disconnected server!");
 };
}</script>
```

How can I implements the same in android

Answer (score 0):

You could try using an android [webview](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) with exactly the same html/js code.